# Random Forest Breiman original article

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, random-forest

Reading:

[https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/randomforest2001.pdf](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/randomforest2001.pdf)

I wanted to ask about clarifications in formula 4. Sorry for not rewriting here all the article, which should be a classic. I would not be able to be more clear than the article itself.

1. $PE^*$ in formula 4 is beforehand defined as :

$PE^*=P_{X,Y}(mg(X,Y)<0)$

but instead I can understand it only if:

$PE^*=P_{X,Y}(mr(X,Y)<0)$

(the margin function $mg$ and the margin function for a random forest $mr$ are defined in the article)

2. My reasoning to show 4 is to apply Chebyshev like this. We know that for a generic r.v. $X$ and $a>0$:

$P(|X-\mu|\ge a)\le Var(X)/a^2$

when $a=\mu>0$ (in the article the expectation is supposed to be positive) this implies:

$P(X\ge 2\mu)+P(X\le 0)\le Var(X)/\mu^2$

so that we can deduce:

$P(X\le 0)\le Var(X)/E[X]^2$

Now with $X=mr$ we have our formula (fixing better strong and weak inequalities).

I would like to know:

- if I am correct in the interpretation of the definition of $PE^*$ in formula 4 ;
- if the argument I provided here is the one used to justify formula 4. If not, what would be the correct one ;

Comment: Your question is too vague and open-ended to be suitable here.  Could you make it more specific?

Comment: Yes sure I can try. What should I do to make it more specific?

Comment: Clarify what "missing something important" might mean.  As it stands, that's a broad subjective phrase.

Comment: Ah ok. So maybe that is easy to change. The new version should be better in this respect.